# Defining resources for a given region

Tags: android, internationalization, resources, regional-settings

I want to create resources for a given regions so I created a batch of `value-rDE` directory for Germany or `value-rUS` for the USA. Now it seems that those directories won't work. The documentation about [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2), points out that it does only work with languages so it should be e.g. `values-de-rDE` or `values-en-rUS`. But what is with combinations like `value-en-rDE` which I also saw in the wild. This would explode the count of directories.

Now I came up with the idea to use the [Mobile country code (MMC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code), which seems to be also an option. Is that reliable? Is there a better way to store region specific information as resources?

### Why do I want to do this?

Just take as an example the [IATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Air_Transport_Association_airport_code) code of the capital city's airport, which does not need to been localizated.